# Why does a command not work as alias?

Tags: bash, alias

Using the command directly works:

```
$ find \
/home...
```

But not as alias:

```
alias synclinks="find \
       /home/foo/Pictures/ \
       -type f -exec file --mime-type {} \+ | \
       awk -F: '{if ($2 ~/image\//) print $1}' \
       | xargs ln -t /home/foo/MyHardlinks"

$ synclinks
```

Returns

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {if ( ~/image\//) print }
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ syntax error
ln: missing file operand
Try 'ln --help' for more information.
find: ‘file’ terminated by signal 13
find: ‘file’ terminated by signal 13
find: ‘file’ terminated by signal 13
find: ‘file’ terminated by signal 13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is double-quoted.  Within the double-quoted command, you use `$1` and `$2`.  Since these are used in a double-quoted string, the shell will replace these with the 1st and 2nd positional parameters (it does not matter that these are within a single-quoted substring inside the double-quoted string).  These are likely empty. This means that your alias would contain `awk` syntax errors.

In this case, I would suggest using a shell function instead.  It is much easier to get the quoting right in a shell function:

```bsh
synclinks () {
    find /home/foo/Pictures/ -type f -exec file --mime-type {} + |
    awk -F: '$2 ~ /image\// { print $1 }' | 
    xargs ln -t /home/foo/MyHardlinks
}
```

You would define this wherever you usually define aliases.

I have only made a tiny adjustment to the `awk` code, but I haven't tested the code in any way.

The `bash` manual contains the statement

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.